# Skipping levels in Ingress

Tags: ingress

The current [level requirements for Ingress](https://ingressmanual.wordpress.com/2014/08/10/ingress-high-level-requirements-9-16/) are as follows:

```
Level   AP          Silver  Gold    Platinum    Black
L9      2,400,000   4       1       0           0
L10     4,000,000   5       2       0           0
L11     6,000,000   6       4       0           0
L12     8,400,000   7       6       0           0
L13     12,000,000  -       7       1           0
L14     17,000,000  -       -       2           0
L15     24,000,000  -       -       3           0
L16     40,000,000  -       -       4           2
```

Considering higher-level requirements do not include less-level medals, is it possible to skip some levels entirely?

For example, would someone who has 17M AP and two platinum medals be promoted to L14, even if he hasn't the 7 gold medals required for L13?

Or are the levels applied sequentially so that L13 is an actual requirement for L14?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Levels are applied in sequence, you can not be promoted to a higher level until you've been through all levels before it, as shown from this profile:

[image: Ingress Agent Profile for Joubarc, L11]

While there is enough AP and the two platinum medals required for L14, I'm still stuck at L11 because I don't have enough gold medals for L12 (or L13).

However, as soon as I get the 7 gold medals required for L13, I should indeed get to L14 immediately. This might be considered as "skipping" L13, but in fact the game will apply the two level ups in sequence. (I'll update to confirm when I reach that point)

Comment: Yes, you will simply level up several times at once. The notification box for the level up will appear several times, once you close one, the next one will follow. This also happened when the level cap was raised from 8 to 16, because the game allowed you to continue collecting AP past the 2.4M required for level 8. So basically every player who had been active after reaching level 8 leveled up several levels at once when that patch went live. I remember people going all the way to level 12 or 13 immediately.